# How to pivot data without aggregations and with variable amount of columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the follwing table:

| machineId | periodId | errorId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AGR0.37576 | 13 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 14 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 14 | ERR458 |
| AGR0.37576 | 15 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 15 | ERR458 |
| AGR0.37576 | 16 | ERR458 |
| AGR0.37576 | 16 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 17 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 17 | ERR458 |
| AGR0.37576 | 18 | ERR458 |
| AGR0.37576 | 18 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 19 | ERR561 |
| AGR0.37576 | 20 | ERR561 |

- "*machineId*" is a uniqueidentifier that identifies the machine we have at hand [**AGR**(agriculture)**0**(a tracktor)**.37576**(the SN of the machine itself)]
- "*periodId*" is a uniqueidentifier for the period: e.g. **13** (2021-12-31), **14** (2022-01-01), etc.
- "*errorId*" is a uniqueidentidier for the error the machine has had in that period. e.g.  **ERR561** - overheating, **ERR457** - coolant level very low, **ERR458** - coolant level very low It can be one or more errors per period. If it is more thane one error a new record with the same period and the new error code is inserted.

I want to pivot and present the table like so:

| machineId | periodId | ERROR1 | ERROR2 | ERROR3 | ERROR4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AGR7.00012 | 9 | ERR221 | MIS061 | ERG737 | SER003 |
| AGR0.37576 | 13 | ERR561 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| ROAD.88887 | 13 | ERR561 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| AGR0.37576 | 14 | ERR845 | ERR561 | ERR737 | NULL |

I have two problems:

**1.** All I could find until now explains more or less how to pivot sales data to some period (Qs, HYs, etc). As you can see the only column, I can aggregate on is the *periodId*, which does not makes sense.

**2.** The amount of errors per period varies, I can have no errors per machine for a given period and 100 for another.
Any ideas how to achieve this using SQL?

Sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #sampleData
CREATE TABLE #sampleData ( [machineId] varchar(18), [periodId] int, [errorId] varchar(13) )

INSERT INTO #sampleData ([machineId], [periodId], [errorId])
VALUES
( 'AGR0.37576', 13, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 14, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 14, 'ERR458' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 14, 'ERR737' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 15, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 15, 'ERR458' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 16, 'ERR458' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 16, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 17, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 17, 'ERR458' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 18, 'ERR458' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 18, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 19, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 20, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 21, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 22, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 29, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 30, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 96, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 97, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 111, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 112, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR0.37576', 113, 'ERR561' ),
( 'AGR7.00012', 9, 'ERR221' ),
( 'AGR7.00012', 9, 'MIS061' ),
( 'AGR7.00012', 9, 'ERG737' ),
( 'AGR7.00012', 9, 'SER003' ),
( 'ROAD.88887', 13, 'ERR561' )
```

Comment: Can you edit the "expected output"?

Comment: SQL Pivoting function can only works with a defined set of values. In your case you seem to want to display the errors by machine/period. This will require custom query using outer apply. What would append to the output when the same errorId occurs for the same period/machine?

Comment: bring more clarity for logic of pivot.

Comment: If you don't know all the potential columns, you'll need a [dynamic PIVOT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.
If you have a finite number of errors then you could do something simple like this

```
-- static column version
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
            *
            , ColNum = CONCAT('Col', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MachineID, PeriodID ORDER BY ErrorID) )
        FROM #sampleData 
    ) s
    PIVOT 
        (
            MIN(ErrorID) 
            FOR [ColNum] IN (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10)
        ) pvt
```

I've added the 'Col' string to the start to make the pivot statement more readable (otherwise the column names would start with numbers).

This statis version will always produce the same number of columns even if they are all blank.

If you want it fully dynamic then you you will have to generate a list of the column names first, the final statement is almost the same as above.

```
-- dynamic version
-- Get a list of column names required
DECLARE @ColNums varchar(1000) = ''
SELECT  @ColNums = CONCAT(@ColNums, ColNum , ', ')
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColNum FROM (
                SELECT 
                        *
                        , ColNum = CONCAT('Col', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MachineID, PeriodID ORDER BY ErrorID) ) --column name per machine/period
                    FROM #sampleData ) c
            ) x

SET @ColNums = LEFT(@ColNums, LEN(@ColNums)-1) -- trim the final comma

-- Generate the final sql
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 
'SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *, ColNum = CONCAT(''Col'', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MachineID, PeriodID ORDER BY ErrorID) )
        FROM #sampleData ) s
    PIVOT 
        (MIN(ErrorID) FOR [ColNum] IN (' + @ColNums + ')) pvt 
    ORDER BY MachineID, PeriodID'

EXEC (@sql)
```

**Note:** The dynamic version also formats the ColNums so the numeric part is always 3 numbers long, this assumes you won't have more than 999 error columns !! If you don't need this much padding, then you can reduce the `D3` to `D2` in the format function.

This gives the following results

[image]

Comment: Hello @Alan,

Both suggestions work perfectly. Thanks a lot for the answer! :)